# Adding listener on canvas points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hey I have a simple triangle in canvas, and I would like to add listener to each triangle's point, so that if user click each point an action will happen.
I would like to know if such procedure is possible in canvas, if not what my alternatives? so my main question is as follows:

1. Can I add a listener on canvas single points? if not what are my alternatives?

**Update:**

I have tried my luck and succeed in adding click event on the all canvas and then get current points of mouse click,but my solution isn't final and very not precious.

**Can I create an area around each point which is clicked so the user will not have to be precious in his clicks?**

http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/VadQYm

```js
$(function(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     var triangle = [{ x: 58, y: 845 }, { x: 984, y: 845 }, { x: 521, y: 41 }];
  drawTriangle(triangle);
    function drawTriangle(t) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(t[0].x, t[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(t[1].x, t[1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(t[2].x, t[2].y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas" width=1024 height=980></canvas>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single point you could attach an event to in your canvas - it is just a drawing Api - a container for your Image (See [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp) for further reference).

But if you have the coordinates, of course you can always detect the clicked position in your Canvas.

I made you a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cd8x6yL8/1/), to show the possible solution.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
function doMouseDown(e) {
for (i = 0; i < triangle.length; ++i) {
  if ((e.x  triangle[i].x) && (e.y === triangle[i].y)) {
    console.log('you hit an edge!');
  }
 }
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to create a tolerance, you have to define the plus and the minus of the actual position you want to accept. A simple and not elegant way could be the following:

```
function tolerance(number){
//define the tolerance here
var tolerance = 15;
//all the accepted numbers within the tolerance will be in this array
var numberArray=[];

for(i=0;i<(tolerance)*2;++i){
    if(i >= tolerance){
        if(i!=tolerance){
            numberArray[i] = numberArray[i-1]-1;
        }else{
            numberArray[i] = number -1;
        }
    }else{
        if(i!=0){
            numberArray[i] = numberArray[i-1]+1;
        }else{
            numberArray[i] = number +1;
        }
    }
}
//don't forget to put the actual number in the array
numberArray.push(number);
return numberArray;
}
```

You can now change the **doMouseDown** function to look something like this:

```
function doMouseDown(e) {
for (k = 0; k < triangle.length; ++k) {
    if ((tolerance(triangle[k].x).indexOf(e.x)!=-1) && (tolerance(triangle[k].y).indexOf(e.y)!=-1)) {
        console.log('you hit an edge!');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes but then the user need to be precious, how can I create an area around each point which is clicked and the operate this procedure?